# Why does cout give 'nan' output?

Tags: c++

My C++ code is giving 'nan' output when I call the function in cout. If I remove the comment tag('//') and call the function without cout, the output is correct.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

double sumOfSquare(double x, double y){
   // cin>> x>> y;
    double sum1 = 0;
    for(double i = x; i <= y; i++){
        sum1 += pow(i , 2);
    }
    //cout<< sum1 <<endl;

}

double squareOfSum(double a, double b){
    double sum2 = 0;
    for(double j = a; j <= b; j++){
        sum2 += j;
        }
       // cout<< pow(sum2, 2) <<endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout<< sumOfSquare(1, 100);
    squareOfSum(1, 100);
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are using C++, don't `#include <math.h>`. Use the C++ wrapped header: `#include <cmath>`.

Answer (score 3):

The functions `sumOfSquare` and `squareOfSum` do not return a value. They should return something in order for `cout` to print them (or for any other code to use the values). So, the two function may return a `NaN` or `0` (on my compiler) or anything else.

**Example:**

```
double sumOfSquare(double x, double y){
   // cin>> x>> y;
    double sum1 = 0;
    for(double i = x; i <= y; i++){
        sum1 += pow(i , 2);
    }
    return sum1;

}

double squareOfSum(double a, double b){
    double sum2 = 0;
    for(double j = a; j <= b; j++){
        sum2 += j;
        }
    return pow(sum2, 2);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, in many compilers, if you do not return a value from a function which expects a return value, it will return a "default" constructed value, which generally is NaN for doubles.